# Apply request post to text in pandas dataframe and save in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with text to analyze via an API. Here's a dummy df for reference:

```
data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3],
        'Text': ['today i went shopping', 'breaking news', 'break up']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'Text'])
```

Essentially, the API outputs the emotion intensity for different emotions for a given text. I want to save these outputs as columns in the original df.

I have written a function that can be applied to each text in the df:

```
def analyze_text(text, df):
    myobj = {'tweet': text}
    x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
    output = x.json()
    #quantitative data
    intensity_scores = output['intensity_scores']
    #save the emotion intensities for respective emotion
    df['Anger'] = intensity_scores['tAnger']
    df['Fear'] = intensity_scores['tSadness']
    df['Sadness'] = intensity_scores['tFear']
    df['Joy'] = intensity_scores['tJoy']
    df['Valence'] = intensity_scores['tValence']
```

How can I ensure that the corresponding intensities this function adds to each row of the df is specific to each row of text? Right now, all 3 texts have the same intensities even though each text is different.

Thanks!

Comment: How looks `output['intensity_scores']` after pass your sample data?

Comment: @jezrael hi! `output['intensity_scores']` is a dictionary with keys 'tAnger', 'tFear', 'tSadness', 'tJoy' and 'tValence'